# Under which cases a "normal" Principal becomes an "anonymousUser"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have an application that uses Spring security. Everything runs fine, users can login/logout, no problems, but sometimes, from time to time, we find a situation where the:

```
requestAuthentication.getPrincipal()
```

returns "anonymousUser", like if all the session info would have been lost.

Any clue what might be happening here?

P.D I could post the (big) filter definitions, but I don't it's going to be of any use, because as I said this just seems to happen randomly.

Comment: maybe you never added the principal? quite a bit depends on your code and config

Comment: I'd review how you're managing sessions (both server-side and client-side). If you're using the traditional JSESSIONID as cookie, do you have an issue with (sub)domain for the cookie? Are you getting SPAM/robot requests without JSESSIONID? Is your app server expiring sessions? Is your app server trying to serialize sessions to disk and failing?